Winter '25 release : onclick on lightning-helptext no longer works?
I have code like this :
<lightning-helptext if:true={iscopyenabled} 
icon-name="utility:copy" 
content="Copy" 
size="small" 
onclick={handlecopy}>
</lightning-helptext

that has ALWAYS honored the onclick event.
Now we have Winter '25 and it doesn't :(
Would someone please confirm this for me? Just a 'yes' I see the same thing or 'no' I don't.
Please don't ask why I'm using lightning-helptext. Just a nice answer to the question, please.
I did a quick check with the lightning-icon component and it continues to work as expected.
The Winter '25 release notes mention this :

lightning-helptext This accessibility is new

Users can now use either mouse clicks or keyboard interactions to launch the tooltip


Not sure I really get what they are saying. The point is something has changed and that mention looks like a 'smoking gun' to me...
Thanks
Peter.

Yes we are also facing the same issue and we have a raised a Salesforce ticket.

This is the expected behaviour. Following the Winter '25 release, the onclick event for lightning-helptext will be used to launch the tooltip.
Reference Doc : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_components.htm&release=252&type=5

Thanks Parag. Yes, I can read the release notes too, which I did. I believe I even mentioned it in the initial question.  I also mentioned that I really didn't understand what 'launching the tooltip' even means :( Do you know what that means by any chance? That could help me better understand why this 'breaking change' was introduced into the mix for this component. thx

and after a few minutes of testing this component I can 'guess' what 'launch' means? Clicking simply toggles the state of the helptext right? Click once it's displayed, click again it's hidden. Almost totally worthless for us, but I can see some 'mobile' use case is being addressed here. Bottom line, this is busted for us, and we'll simply write our own component

Yes you are right! @PeterByrne
